# how to call asp.net webservice method from angular js ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax

i want to call a string method from webservice.asmx.cs class by uisng angularjs ajax concept to show a popup message uisng alert method. Here belows are the codes that what i have

```js
 
var obj = angular.module("myapp", []);        
        obj.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $http)
        {
            //$scope.student = [];            
                $http({
                    url: "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    method: "GET",
                    data: "",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'dataType': 'json' }
                })
                .success(function (response) {                    
                    alert(resp.d);

                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myapp">
    <h1>Sample Application</h1>    
    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
      
    </div>
</body>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{ 

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
}
```

finally when i run the above codes it does not work. Neither it is showing any alert message nor any errors. it only shows a blank window with that h1 tag. need help!

Comment: You need to add angular script to your page..after angular reference..

Comment: i have written that too see the above codes @PankajParkar

Comment: I was wrong. in that case you would get `$moduler` error.. could you try to put debugger in your javascript file.. and see where exactly it gets stuck